# PHP message after Session timeout does not show up

Tags: php

I have a flash message that is supposed to display after 30 minutes. It seems that if the user leaves it idle for 1+ hours the message does not pop up. I'm not sure why. I have tried destroying the session after a few seconds and the message appears every single time. I am not sure what is going on . Here is the code.

```
<?php
// session_cache_limiter('private');
/* set the cache expire to 5 minutes */
// session_cache_expire(1);    
// if(time()-$_SESSION["login_time_stamp"] > 1800) 
session_start();


function checkInactivity()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION["login_time_stamp"])) {
        if (time() - $_SESSION["login_time_stamp"] > 1800 ) {
            deleteSession();
            redirect("public/index.php?url=pages/sessionExpired");
            exit;
        }
    }
}

function setSessionTimeStamp()
{
    return $_SESSION["login_time_stamp"] = time();
}

function deleteSession()
{
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
}
checkInactivity();
```

If the session is greater than 1800 seconds(30 minutes) it redirects you to sessionExpired controller.

```
<?php
class Pages extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
  }
  public function index()
  {
    // phpinfo();
    if (isset($_SESSION['dealerCode'])) {
      redirect('public/index.php?url=Dealer/index');
    } 
     else {
      $this->view('pages/index');
    }
  }
  public function sessionExpired()
  {
        flash("session",'You were logged out due to inactivity',"alert alert-warning");
        redirect('public/index.php?url=pages/index');
  }
}
```

It's frustrating since I have to wait 30 minutes to see if it shows up or not. It does destroy the session and it does redirect me to the login page. So I feel it does seem to point to sessionExpired method which then redirects me to the login page.

In my head the logic works. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: What are your PHP settings, regarding session lifetime and garbage collection? Maybe the garbage collector has removed the session file in the meantime already? Then `isset($_SESSION["login_time_stamp"])` would of course not be true any more, and then your whole validity check doesn't do _anything_ any more ...

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you. I see this setting in my php.ini file. 
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
I assume there is a similar setting on the server. I am going to increase the time and see if it works.

Comment: @CBroe I changed the settings in the PHP.ini file. Nothing seemed to happen. I changed the session.gc_maxlifetim to 5 seconds. I then left my application open for 5 minutes to see if I could get the logout message to stop showing up. The would verify that this was the culprit to my issue. However, regardless if I set it to 1 or 5 second the session was still valid and I was able to see the message.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up involving JavaScript. I changed the values of the PHP.ini file and I was still receiving inconsistent behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let url = urlSelect.sessionTimeOutUrl;

  if (window.location.href.indexOf("pages/index") === -1) {
    // Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    let idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute

    let idleTime = 0;

    // Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
      idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
      idleTime = 0;
    });
    function timerIncrement() {
      idleTime = idleTime + 1;
      console.log(idleTime);
      if (idleTime > 40) {
        // 59 minutes
        window.location.replace(url);
      }
    }
  }
});
```